# Question by reverting position of verb and noun for people

Tags: questions, ordre-des-mots

There is this sentence:

> Marie aime la peinture.

and the question for it:

> Marie aime-t-elle la peinture ?

Why cannot it be the following:

> Aime Marie la peinture ?

Why is *Marie* placed at first position and 'elle' is added after the verb? ([source](http://www.frenchtutorial.com/standard/interrogative/convert.php))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you can revert the subject and the verb only when the subject is a pronoun (probably for euphonic reasons).

So when the subject is a noun (or a noun group), it is kept before the verb and the corresponding pronoun is added after the verb.